# Trying to merge two string values together

Tags: php, sql

im trying to get two separate columns of a database to CONCAT together in a check.

What i currently have is

```
<?php

$retrieve = "SELECT * FROM `Dogs` WHERE CONCAT(`Date`, 
`Time`) =". $_GET["id"];

$result = $conn->query($retrieve);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo $row['Name'] . $row['Date'] . 
$row['Time'];

}
?>
```

However, it doesn't seem to be compiling, and im stumped as to where i've gone wrong with it, as it should be merging the two together?
I know the Get is working as i have an echo printing it out, and does so correctly.

Any guidance is helpful

The error i receive, is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':00:00' at 
line 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Also: You should use parameterized queries. Read: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+sql+injection)

Comment: @stickybit hi, thanks for your response. As far as i can tell, i'm using the appropriate quotes? And i plan o ntackling parameterized queries after i get the actual queries working

Comment: So `$_GET["id"]` is `'DateTime'`?

Comment: @stickybit `$_GET["id]` is `Date+Time` as they're two seperate columns int he database. So the `$_GET["id]` is a string of the two merged together in a singular string, not added together mathematically

Comment: Your not concatenating columns but literals. Your quotes are wrong for what you want to do.

Comment: Side note: Don't store date and time as (two) `integers`. Use an appropriate data type like `datetime`.

Comment: @stickybit `"SELECT * FROM ``performance`` WHERE CONCAT(``PerfDate`` ``PerfTime``)  =". $_GET["id"];` i've tried using these quote's for it too, and still an error. ignore the fact they're double quoted here, was the only was i could format it. In my code its quoted singular

Comment: There's no comma between the arguments to `concat()`...

Comment: @stickybit oh sorry i think i actually somehow deleted it from my comment, my code does have a comma in between the arguments and still doesn't work

Comment: @stickybit i updated the post with the correct quotes and the error message

Comment: Again: Use an appropriate data type and parameterized queries.

Comment: @stickybit i'm unfortunately unable to change the data type of the database, and i'm going to parameterize the query once it's working. So in short im unable to change it to DateTime and have to merge the two strings together